# CakePHP Console via Cron Question

Tags: windows, cakephp, cron

I'm using the CakePHP Console to download files from we and processed in a database. I'm running the console from inside the "app" directory. But when I'm trying to run the console outside app and by just setting the "-app" parameter for my cron job, it doesn't work.

To be honest, I've had no success using -app parameter. It's like it's not working at all.

By the way, I'm using Windows & Pycron for my cron jobs.

Here's what happens when I'm trying to run the console from D:\

```
D:\>web\elink\cake\console\cake -app D:\web\elink\app


Welcome to CakePHP v1.2.2.8120 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
Current Paths:
 -app: app
 -working: D: -app D:/web/elink/app
 -root: D: -app D:/web/elink
 -core: D:\web\elink

Changing Paths:
your working path should be the same as your application path
to change your path use the '-app' param.
Example: -app relative/path/to/myapp or -app /absolute/path/to/myapp

Available Shells:

 D:\web\elink\vendors\shells:
         - none

 CORE\console\libs:
         acl
         api
         bake
         console
         i18n
         schema
         testsuite

To run a command, type 'cake shell_name [args]'
To get help on a specific command, type 'cake shell_name help'
```

My shells are located at D:\web\elink\app\vendors\shells.

Comment: i can't seem to get the -app parameter to work on Ubuntu either. i will try the workaround listed below by hector.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to reproduce this issue using versions `1.2.2.8120` and `1.2.3.8166` on Windows. The `-app` parameter doesn't seem to work at all as expected.

The console will only list global shells in the `/vendors/shells` folder and not application-specific ones located in `/app/vendors/shells` or in plugins (`/app/plugins/plugin_name/vendors/shells`).

The `-app` parameter works as expected on OpenSUSE, listing all available application-specific shells (including those in plugins).

Unless we are doing something incorrectly, it is probably worth opening a ticket on [Trac](http://trac.cakephp.org) about this issue.

A workaround would be to add your Cake `console` directory to the Windows `PATH` environment variable.

1. Open 'System Properties' (`Start` key + `Pause/Break` key)
2. Open 'Advanced' tab
3. Click 'Environment Variables'
4. Select the PATH variable in the 'System variables' section
5. Press 'Edit'
6. Append `;E:\web\elink\cake\console\` to the 'Variable value'
7. Press 'Okay' on all dialogs
8. Close all open `cmd` prompts

You can then set up `pycron` to run `E:\web\elink\cake` without the `-app` parameter and all your application-specific shells should be available.

Comment: I've done this but when I type cake, the application-specific shells still don't show up. However, this time the -app parameter works as expected. 

Thanks deizel.

Answer (score 1):

-For the people having the same problem but on linux systems, here there is an easy solution:

http://book.cakephp.org/complete/3/The-Manual#Running-Shells-as-cronjobs-846

-Another alternative solution for any system would be to create a simple script with two lines like this:

```
cd /path/to/app
/path/to/cake
```

-Both solutions worked for me in a Cent0S and in a MacOS based machines.